# Checking Text Backspace Issue

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield, documentfilter

I made it where a button is disabled and the only way to enable it is to type text into a field.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

class checkText extends DocumentFilter {
public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,         String text,
    AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
    super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
    main.enableButton();
   }
  }

public class main extends JFrame {
static JFrame inputFrame = new JFrame();
static JTextField myTextfield = new JTextField(10);
static JButton myButton = new JButton("Test");

public main() {
inputGUI();
}

private static void inputGUI() {
inputFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
inputFrame.setTitle("The INPUT");
inputFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
inputFrame.setSize(640, 480);
inputFrame.setVisible(true);
inputFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

inputFrame.add(myButton);

DocumentFilter filter = new checkText();
((AbstractDocument) myTextfield.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(filter);
inputFrame.add(myTextfield);
myButton.setEnabled(false);
}

public static void enableButton() {
myButton.setEnabled(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) { new main(); }
}
```

Whenever I backspace and erase all the text. The button is still active. How do I disable it back when there are no text inside the field?

Comment: Can you get length of the input? If it's length equals zero than disable it

Comment: @PeerNet: you can, but it's convoluted. Just checking the Document in the filter's methods is not adequate. You'd also have to check what the super method would do to the Document. That's why using a DocumentListener would be **much** simpler.

Comment: Kerperlo: in the future, please consider using indentation in your code. Your flat code is very hard to read and parse.

Comment: I note you've asked several question with title in the form *"Java [Checking Text Backspace Issue]"*.  The major tag is automatically prefixed to the page title so should not be included in the question title.  That makes the square brackets unnecessary.  So that title should be *"Checking Text Backspace Issue"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your DocumentFilter never checks the Document or what affect the filter's methods would have on the Document so you shouldn't be surprised that it's not working. Your also only overriding one out of the three DocumentFilter methods. Also, your main class has an `enableButton()` but there's no way for outside classes to disable the button. ....

Myself, I wouldn't use a DocumentFilter but rather a DocumentListener since you want to check the Document **after** the text changes have been registered, not before, and so using a DocumentFilter would only confuse the issue. I'd simply check the length of the text in the Document and that would be all that was needed. To get the Document, call `getDocument()` on the DocumentEvent object passed into all overridden methods. Then simply call `getLength()` on this. If it's > 0, enable the button, else disable it.

e.g.,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.Document;


public class Main2 extends JPanel {
   private JButton testButton = new JButton("Test");
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField(11);

   public Main2() {
      add(testButton);
      add(textField);

      testButton.setEnabled(false);
      textField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

         @Override
         public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            checkDoc(e);
         }

         @Override
         public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            checkDoc(e);
         }

         @Override
         public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            checkDoc(e);
         }

         private void checkDoc(DocumentEvent e) {
            Document doc = e.getDocument();
            testButton.setEnabled(doc.getLength() > 0);
         }
      });
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Main2 mainPanel = new Main2();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. If I had more rep I would give you the rep needed.